# Cannot Edit channel entries in the MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager

We are using Expression engine 2.6.2. We have the MSM set up.

Recently we updated all the modules inside that we are using. And after that when we want to edit the channel entries in one of the sites in MSM , the system doesn't allow us to do so.

When we hit submit after making our changes, it shows **"You must select a valid template for displaying this page."**. But the default_site works just fine.

Does this have anything to do with updating the MSM ? We have googled for a solution but unfortunately couldn't find any..!!

Please kindly help us to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Pages Module? Or another add-on that associates templates to entries at the entry level? That error doesn't sound directly MSM related.

Comment: Yes - make sure your Pages Module settings are referring to valid templates that are where they're supposed to be on the server.